# URL rewriting makes all the links of same patterns after visiting any rewritten link in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, urlrewriter

I am using `UrlRewriter` to rewrite my urls in an ASP.NET application. Everything works fine and the work which I need to do is working ok.

I want to redirect `~/product/45/something` to `~/show_product_details.aspx?current_prod=45`

and it's working fine. But the problem is when I request `~/product/45/something`, I am getting the page from `~/show_product_details.aspx?current_prod=45`. After that when I click some link like `~/home.aspx`, it again redirects me to `~/product/45/home.aspx`.

Please suggest how to fix this. I am using this rule:

```
          <add name="Gallery1" virtualUrl="^~/product/(.*)/(.*)" 
                 rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
                destinationUrl="~/show_product_details.aspx?current_prod=$1"
         ignoreCase="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the URLs in your ASP.NET application are not resolved to the root of the application, but rather are relative links, causing the folder structure to be taken into account.

If you are using ASP.NET Web Forms you need to ensure you either call ResolveUrl("~/home.aspx") when outputting the URL, or ensure that the hyperlink is runat=server, for example:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/home.aspx">Home</a>
```

OR:

```
<a href='<%# ResolveUrl("~/home.aspx") %>'>Home</a>
```

Another way you can resolve this is to have a base reference in your HTML, which tells the browser that ALL links on the page must be rooted at the specified path:

In the `<head>` section:`<base href='http://www.yourwebsite.com/' />`

Comment: Mr. Duffman the trick worked i added a runat="server" and changed the path from home.aspx to ~/home.aspx.   plz help me in another issue.i am using a lightbox kit to show my images in a modal slideshow with the help of that lightbox kit .i am doing this adding a rel=lightbox  in every <a href="" rel="lightbox"></a> tag.Problem is before urlrewriting the modals were working but after rewriting the url modals are not working i mean lightbox is not working.plz help

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error?  Is your JS file being downloaded correctly?  Maybe the javascript is being caught in your rewrite rule.  I haven't used Lightbox before.

Comment: yes sir i am getting a javascript error and the js file is not being downloaded.how to prevent the js file to prevent getting caught in rewrite rule.i implemented a stop processing rule for js files.still not working